# Get the regular price from the order object when catalog discount is applied?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

in Magento 2 how we can get the regular price for the product from the order object when the catalog discount is applied to the products.

As order object only return the discounted price and no discount information is present so we can get the actual price.

We can get the price by getting the product ID. but what is the product price change and we capture the order after that ??

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {    
    $productID = $item->getProductId();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get regular price using following code:

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {    
$regularPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice();
```

}

Comment: how we can get the same thing in Magento 1.9.x ?

Comment: same way like Magento 2, as database is same and method is available for item object Magento 1.9.x

Comment: Original Price of the product is 660 and I am getting 594 with inc tax and after discount configuration.